# Displaying an integer variable in TextView

Tags: android, android-activity, textview, int

I have an `int` that depends on users input. How do I display that `int` on the screen?

Here is what I have been attempting:

```
    <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="@int/HW"  // What goes here, This is where i am confused
    tools:context=".DisplayMessageActivity" />
```

Also here are my defined variables, you may have seen my post not too long ago about this program:

```
    // Receive messages from options page
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    int HW = intent.getIntExtra("MESSAGE_HW", 0);
    int OTW = intent.getIntExtra("MESSAGE_OTW", 0);
    int HPD = intent.getIntExtra("MESSAGE_HPD", 0);
```

I am trying to display the int HW on the screen, any help is greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: you want to display it on the same page? or a different one?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> *android:text="@int/HW"  // What goes here, This is where i am confused*

A default value can go there. Something that would tell you that the `TextView` has not been populated yet.

> *How do i display that int on the screen?*

To display the `int` on the screen inside the `TextView` you have shown us. You need to get the `TextView` in your `Activity` with something similar to the following:

```
TextView textView = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.textViewId);
```

Then you can set the text on that `textView` with the following:

```
textView.setText(String.valueOf(HW));
```

---

Here is an example of adding the id to your xml:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewId"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="@int/HW"  // What goes here, This is where i am confused
    tools:context=".DisplayMessageActivity" />
```

Comment: I tried this but the only that shows up on the screen when i run it on my phone is 0, i have to default set to 7 also so i dont see why it would have 0? no matter what number i put it in its always 0

Answer (score 2):

When you get the users input, do this:

```
TextView hwTextView = (TextView)findViewById("R.id.hwTextView")
hwTextView.setText(String.valueOf(yourIntVariable));
```

Note this means you'll have to add an id attribute to your TextView with the value of "hwTextView"

Answer (score 1):

Building on prolink007's answer, you could also omit that line then call `setText`, java side.

```xml
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/hw"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    tools:context=".DisplayMessageActivity" />
```

```java
TextView HWgetText = (TextView)findViewById("R.id.hw");
HWgetText.setText(String.valueOf(HW));
```